# Simple care for baby tokay

Tags: geckos

Today I met in my house what I believe is a baby tokay. It's about the size of a small common house gecko, but it is black with faint white dots and less shy.

It's currently under my sofa.

Does it need anything? Should I provide a tiny bowl of water? Sausage? Chicken egg? I don't have any worms, crickets, flies or the like. (There are probably a few ants under the sofa.) Should I better chase it outside (I'm in Thailand, so it's warm) or leave it there?

I don't plan on keeping it as a pet, but I don't mind it staying with me for a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He will be okay regardless what you do, these guys are nocturnal so he'll probably try to find his way out at night.

They are good at fitting into small spaces so I'm sure he will find something to snack on inside, these guys can also last quite some time without food or water.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer; also note worthy, they can give a nasty bite to humans, so don't poke your hand under the sofa.

> These animals have an unpleasant disposition and can inflict severe bites when handled.

http://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Gekko_gecko/

As you mentioned in the comments it's only 4cm long, it's only young. I would be checking if it is still there after a day and if it is, get someone to help you lift the couch during the daylight (when it's not active) and pop a container over the gecko.

slide a stiff piece of paper under the container and take it out to the garden. Such a young lizard may have trouble navigating back to the outdoors and if so, may need your assistance. There would be a small risk it could dehydrate if it doesn't move from under the couch.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, but it's like 4 cm long, I can't even imagine it has any teeth yet.

Comment: @AndreKR no worries. I'd be checking if it's still there. If not try and get someone to help you move it out after a day. If it can't find it's own way out, it could dehydrate. Updated my answer to reflect this